# Predicting Outcome Variable for out-of-sample Panel data R

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have data for population, income and price of cheese in 139 countries from 2007 to 2017.

[image]

The objective is to find the price of bread in a new country X where I have data on the population and income in country X from 2007 to 2017. Due to evidence of heterogeneity across countries as well as years, I utilised a two-way fixed effects model.

```
pdf_fe_2 <- plm(p_cheese_doll ~ pop + inc_doll, data=pdf, model="within", effect="twoways")
```

and obtained the following output

[image]
However, I am now unsure how to calculate the estimated price of cheese in the country X from 2007:2017 as individual fixed effects for country X are to be estimated as well.

Can anyone explain how I can do this? Thanks!