# Can a fixed effect model be used for making predictions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, panel-data, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Im new to panel data, and I am struggling to figure out if paneldata regressions can be used for making predictions outside of the sample to which it was generated.

Thanks,
Mathias

Comment: related if not duplicated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331567/predicting-outcome-variable-for-out-of-sample-panel-data-r